# Vim :s replace specific N < g occurrences on a line

Tags: linux, vim, vi

i am try to use a comma (,) to separate the thousands in the first two numeric fields using `vim command`

```
%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\);/\1,\2\3\4;/g
```

but in this case it gonna add comma also to 9,995 in the second line , what can i use to replace specific N < g occurrences .

input

```
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30275;28686;v2.0 ;beta (1998-03-17)
Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21957;7621;v13.00 sfnt rev 9995; Pen-Ji (2010-08-24)
```

expected output

```
 BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 ;beta (1998-03-17)
 Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;7,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 9995; Pen-Ji (2010-08-24)
```

Comment: your %s command gives exactly the same result as you "expected" `9995` is untouched, as it's not ending with `;` But `7621` is modified, as you expected.

Comment: I edited the question, but anyway how can I do it ? any idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to repeat the last command: `@:` also, you could specify the number of repeats, for example: `10@:`.

So, start from replacing only first match: `%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\);/\1,\2\3\4;/`

Then, as we already have done one of N substitution, repeat it N-1 times.

For example, to replace the first 10 numbers, use:

```
%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\);/\1,\2\3\4;/
9@:
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a shorter and more manageable search pattern:

```
:%s/\(\d\)\(\d\{3}\);/\1,\2;/g
```

Then, I would drop the `/g` flag to only substitute the first match on each line, since the goal is specifically *not* to substitute all matches on all lines:

```
:%s/\(\d\)\(\d\{3}\);/\1,\2;
```

Then, I would repeat the last substitution on every line:

```
g&
```

See `:help \d`, `:help \{`, `:help :s_flags`, and `:help g&`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would advise you to clean up your regex:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3}\);/\1,\2;/g
```

Secondly the `g` flag in the end makes vim replace all occurrences. Without the flag, it will just replace the first one. Since `%` runs the substitution on each line, `%s//g` will replace the first occurrence on every line.

Since you want to replace the first TWO occurrences you could just run it twice. However we want to be a bit elegant here. There is the `:&` command to repeat the last substitution. We can even chain them together:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3}\);/\1,\2;/ | norm %&
```

**Update:**
The other solutions can be used the same way:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3}\);/\1,\2;/ | norm g&
```

or

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3}\);/\1,\2;/ | norm :@
```

Comment: One `|` is enough.

Comment: @romainl thank you that was a typo that gives the line a wrong meaning!
Anyway, I just saw your answer, sorry I was already writing mine, they are quite similar. I like the `g&` operator you used, it seems to be cleaner because of the flags. However it does open a quickfix window if chained together. Do you have any idea why? This way I would still go for the context sensitive `%&`

Comment: Well, the three answers are quite similar and show, if anything, how rich and expressive Vim can be. As for chaining `g&`, it's a normal mode command so it can't be used directly on the command-line without `:help :normal`. If you want chaining, `:%s` is definitely the way to go. Also note that the first answer adresses the `N` part of the question in a way ours don't.

Comment: I am i bit confused now. `%&` Does also open the quickfix if there are more than the 2 lines in the example (just copied them). So I also have to use `norm`. It seems `| @:` and `| %&` do not open quickfix on 2 lines. But they do on more lines... which can be suppressed with `norm`. So I guess my answer is the worst here, because it does not take over the flags like `| norm g&` and isn't generic on more repeats like `| @:`.

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers above, but I'll share how I'd approach it.  (Because I don't want to count how many is "N", and I don't want to repeat the substitutions only to find I did one too many, etc.)

I would use one of the substitutions listed above, like `:%s/\(\d\)\(\d\{3}\);/\1,\2;/g`.  Then I'd run a second substitution, searching for "rev " and removing a comma if it exists:

```
%s/\(rev \d\),\(\d\{3\};\)/\1\2/g
%                               g  all lines, and all occurences on a line
 s/                       /    /   substitute
   \(      \) \(        \)         backref capture groups
     rev \d                        text "rev " and a digit (backref 1)
             ,                     comma
                \d\{3\};           three digits and a semicolon (backref 2)
                           \1\2    backrefs 1 and 2
```

Some things to note --

- If you know the "rev " appears only once on a line, then you can omit the `g` at the end of the substitution.
- If somehow "rev " appears in other
  contexts in the file -- maybe in text like "Foo bar abbrev 4,321" --
  then you'd want to account for that.
- If there are no matches of "rev " followed by a digit and a comma, then Vim will give a "pattern not found" message.

Also, this searches for a four-digit number with a comma.  If there's a chance of five-digits or 6-digits numbers where you'd want to remove the comma, then you'd use this, which is almost the same:

```
%s/\(rev \d\{1,3\}\),\(\d\{3\}\);/\1\2/g
         \d\{1,3\}  ,                     1 to 3 digits followed by a comma
```